# usage of "at the latest" when expressing time

Tags: time

When using "at the latest", is this correct usage?

"I will be in around 10am or 11am at the latest".

Comment: You are only short of a comma after *10am*, if that's what you really meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase *at the latest* means *no later than*.

"I will be in around 10am or 11am at the latest" means *I will be there by 11 am or earlier.*

It is somewhat ambiguous to say *10am or 11am at the latest* since 10am is obviously not the latest, 11am is. Many would understand this to mean

> I am hoping for 10am, but surely by 11am

Given the tone, I wouldn't even bank on noon.

Comment: Your interpretation is quite different. The OP seems to have meant a comma after *10am*. That should be fine.

Comment: @Kris I agree that the comma removes the logical ambiguity, but my view about the real time of arrival remains.